# I can't send mail using PHP mail function... I am getting an error

Tags: php

I am unable to send mail using the PHP mail() function. I am getting an error message. What's wrong in it? Please, help me...

`Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25,  verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in E:\xampp\htdocs\SimpleEmail.php on line 14`

`Email could not be sent.`

```
 <html>
          <head>
            <title>Simple Send Mail Form</title>
        </head>
         <body>
          <h1>Mail Form</h1>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="SimpleEmail.php">
       <table>
         <tr><td><b>To</b></td><td><input type="text" name="mailto" size="35"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Subject</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="mailsubject" size="35"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Message</b></td>
      <td><textarea name="mailbody" cols="50" rows="7"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
      </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
   </form>
      </body>
     </html>  

      //SimpleEmail.php//

         <?php
      if (empty ($mailto) ) {
    die ( "Recipient is blank! ") ;
    }

if (empty ($mailsubject) ){
   $mailsubject=" " ;
}

if (empty ($mailbody) ) {
   $mailbody=" " ; 
}

$result = mail ($mailto, $mailsubject, $mailbody) ;

if ($result) {
   echo "Email sent successfully!" ;
}else{
   echo "Email could not be sent." ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Simple, you don't have an email server running on SMTP port. You need one for mail function to be able to send email

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running your own mail server and aren't configured to use anyone else's. So where would the mail go? Talk to the system administrator or hosting provider.

Comment: how i should configure SMTP on my system

Comment: Talk to your network administrator or hosting provider. Most likely, your provider offers an email service. You don't want to run a mail server unless you have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

the error message mean you need to install SMTP server to let the mail function work normally .
since you using xampp you may configure Mercury Server which comes with XAMPP .. 
once you install it and configure it the mail function will work normally ..

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry...in our local servers many of them doesnot run based on SMTP (Simple Mail Transfor Protocol) so that we con't send the mails but some servers may run on that and if you configured into SMTP protocol port then you can also send them

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test your PHP mail script in your localhost by follow given steps in this tutorial.
http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/

May it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to send an email

```
ini_set("SMTP","aspmx.l.google.com");
$to = "yourmailid@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "toemail@gmail.com";
$headers  = 'From: '.$from. "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$from. "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) echo "Mail Sent.";
```